# Find json object by key and replace it with other object from complex/nested json array

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, jsonpath

I'm trying to find json object by a property/key from a complex/nested json array and replace it with other json object in an angular project.

I have used lodash to find json object by key but the json path of object can be anywhere on json array.

**Here is my sample json array:**

```
{
  "type": "form",
  "title": "title",
  "name": "name",
  "display": "form",
  "path": "path",
  "components": [
    {
      "mask": false,
      "tableView": true,
      "alwaysEnabled": false,
      "label": "",
      "rows": [
        [
          {
            "components": [
              {
                "key": "key1",
                "valueProperty": "value",
                "selectedKey": "ValueKey"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "components": [
              {
                "components": [
                  {
                    "key": "key2",
                    "valueProperty": "value",
                    "selectedKey": "ValueKey"
                  }
                ],
                "allowMultipleMasks": false,
                "showWordCount": false,
                "showCharCount": false,
                "alwaysEnabled": false,
                "type": "textfield",
                "input": true,
                "widget": {
                  "type": ""
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "components": [
              {
                "labelPosition": "left-left",
                "allowMultipleMasks": false,
                "showWordCount": false,
                "showCharCount": false,
                "alwaysEnabled": false,
                "input": true,
                "widget": {
                  "type": ""
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ],
      "header": [],
      "numCols": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to find the entire json object if it contains "selectedkey" property and replace with other object.

**Expected Result:**

```
Json object { "key": "key1", "valueProperty": "value", "selectedKey": "ValueKey" } should be replaced with { "key": "key1", "valueProperty": "value", "selectedKey": "ValueKey" }
```

**Note**: Json object can appear at n number of times and json path of object can be anywhere in json array.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** If you just want to check if that property exists, you can stringify the object and do an `includes` check, like this:

```
function containsKey(obj, key) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj).includes(key);
}

//OR

function containsKey(obj, key) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(key) !== -1;
}
```

You can use this to replace the whole object with a conditional block:

```
if (containsKey(obj, 'selectedKey')) {
    obj = otherObj;
}
```

**ADDITIONAL SOLUTION:** I also adapted my earlier solution that replaced the `selectedKey` to just check for the key. The advantage of this solution is that the function will return immediately after finding the `selectedKey`, as opposed to `JSON.stringify`, which will iterate over every property and value.

```
function containsKey(obj, targetKey) {

    // if the obj is an array, iterate it and call containsKey
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            return containsKey(obj[i], targetKey);
        }
    } else {
        // if it's not an array, it will be an obj
        let keys = Object.keys(obj);
        let key, value;

        // iterate the keys of the object
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            key = keys[i];
            value = obj[key];

            // if we find the target key, return true
            // otherwise, call containsKey on any objects
            if (key === targetKey) {
                return true;
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                return containsKey(value, targetKey);
            }
        }
    }

    /* by this time we've checked every property of the object,
       so we know it does not contain the property or it would
       have returned true */
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan for your response. As per my understanding, above code would replace the value of matched key in a json object but am trying to replace whole object with other object if it contains "selectedkey" key.

Comment: I updated my solution to check for the existence of the property and added a conditional you can use to replace the object; is that more of what you were looking for?